Получение токена абстрактного класса Python
Решил проверить, что делает метод abc.get_cache_token(), однако не понимаю, почему при выводе токена, все время печатает одно и тоже значение. Исходя из определения, я бы хотел знать, что это версия кэша и зачем сравнивать?

Токен представляет собой непрозрачный объект (поддерживающий проверку
на равенство), идентифицирующий текущую версию кэша абстрактного
базового класса для виртуальных подклассов.

import abc
import unittest
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class Test_Environment(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
            @abstractmethod
            def func(self):
                raise NotImplementedError

        class B(A):
            def func(self):
                print("inheritance")


        Otoken = abc.get_cache_token()
        obj = B()
        Ntoken = abc.get_cache_token()
        self.assertEqual(Otoken, Ntoken, 'equal')
        print(Otoken, Ntoken)

mc = Test_Environment()
mc.test()


27 27 вывод

При этом, комментарий equal, в методе assertEqual, не вывелся и никак не среагировал.

Токен обновляется только тогда, когда вы связываете класс-предок с ненаследным классом через вызов статического метода register. Так как в вашем примере класс B явным образом наследует классу A, метод A.register не вызывается.
Если вы хотите увеличить значение токена, переделайте пример
class Test_Environment(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
            @abstractmethod
            def func(self):
                raise NotImplementedError
        class B:
            def func(self):
                print("inheritance")

        Otoken = abc.get_cache_token()
        A.register(B)
        Ntoken = abc.get_cache_token()
        obj = B()
        self.assertTrue(issubclass(B, A))
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(obj, A))
        self.assertEqual(Otoken, Ntoken, 'equal')
        print(Otoken, Ntoken)

При такой последовательности операций assertEqual отвалится:
AssertionError: 26 != 27 : equal


для чего мы используем issubclass и isinstance? если мы и так знаем, что после register, класс B наследуется? Для проверки на наследование и экземпляр?

@Radiance это исключительно для проверки/демонстрации, что ABC.register Работает - объект, который в стандартной структуре типов не является производным от A таки является объектом типа А.

Может ли быть такое, что B является подклассом A, но не имеет экземпляра класса, как в указано в строке isinstance(obj, A)?

Получается, что issubclass и isinstance всегда проверяют сначала, что child class действительно child?

@Radiance и нет, B не наследует A. Если распечатать B.__bases__, там только <class object>.  В случае с абстрактными типами лучше говорить реализует, так как у B и A нет общего кода.

Логично, мы реализуем интерфейс. Получается, что issubclass и isinstance проверяют на наличие реализации?

@Radiance  isinstance  и issubclass вызывают магические методы __intancecheck__ и __subclasscheck__, если те определены. В случае с абстрактными базовыми классами не делается проверка по дереву наследования. И не делается проверка методов. Тупо проверяется, что тип B зарегистрирован как производный от типа А.

Реализацию магических методов абстрактных классов см. здесь: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f420bdd29fbc1a97ad20d88075c38c937c1f8479/Lib/_py_abc.py#L92
